# Fixed top-menu troubles

Tags: html, css

I'm having a top menu bar in my website that is fixed-positioned.
When I switched it to fixed (it placed 'normally' before) I found a trouble - the next div that is hidden under became hidden under the top menu bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />
    <title>Title Goes Here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <img src="logo.png" id="logo" href="index.html" />
        <a class="menu">HOME</a>
        <a class="menu">FAQ</a>
        <a class="menu">TESTIMONIALS</a>
        <a class="menu">CONTACT</a>
        <a class="menu"><img src="login.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="countdown">
        <p id="countdown_title1">Run a customizable, web based</p>
        <p id="countdown_title2">Purim Project Fundraiser</p>
        <p id="countdown_title3"><a>COUNTING DOWN TO PURIM:</a>Mar 16 2015</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

default.css

```
body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
}
p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top{
    padding-top: 27.5px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
    padding-left: 328.1px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}
#countdown{
    background-image: url("../index_contdown.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 519px;
    padding-top: 88px;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    color: #ffffff;
}
#countdown_title1{
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-left: 555px;
    padding-top: 70.5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#countdown_title2{
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 472.5px;
}
#countdown_title3{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
#countdown_title3 a{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #2e7db6;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
#logo{
    margin-right:263.5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu{
    padding-right:37.5px;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: "Raleway"; /* need to fix this with src so that also user without that font will be able to see it. */
}
.menu img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: FYI: `padding-left: 328.1px;` is a huge gap!

Comment: I tried to centerize this div.

Comment: It's not going to be centered on different screen sizes.  I would recommend reading http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to push the div that is hidden by the fixed header down by a margin equal to the height of the fixed header.

This is because when you mark an element as `fixed`, it will stop pushing down the `div` that is below it.  Thus, you'll have to manually push down the `div` with margins to an amount equal to the height of the header.

**EDIT:**

Push down the content with `padding-top` instead of `margin-top` in order to avoid having to use `top: 0;` on the other `div`

Comment: I tried to do that but for some reason the margin-top that is located in the #countdown is pushing the #top too

Comment: Then put `top: 0` on the `#top` element.

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly. what does the 'top' property means?

Comment: It depends on the positioning of the element, here's a great resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top